# Pure Dart package with optional Flutter dependency?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a hyphenation package.

Determining the hyphens can be done in pure Dart only.

However, I want to add a helper method `wrapWithFlutter(text, maxWidth)`. It wraps the text and adds hyphens when needed.

For the size calculations `TextPainter` from Flutter is needed.

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

**Question**

If the consumer never calls `wrapWithFlutter(text)`, will Flutter be removed during compilation?

The compiler should tree-shake Flutter like any other unused package.

I have no idea what is going on behind the scenes and I would like to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

The solution some have chosen is to make a _flutter version of your package that uses the dart version of your package.  Then, if someone's in a flutter world, they can choose that instead of the other.